# SonarQube Report Shows Uncovered Conditions for Minimal Vue.js Extension File Changes

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, sonarqube, code-coverage, sonarqube-scan

I'm encountering an issue with my SonarQube report generated locally for a Vue.js extension file. Despite making only three lines of code changes, the report indicates 22 uncovered conditions, adversely affecting my overall coverage report percentage. Can someone help figure out this issue?

```
import Emitter from "tiny-emitter/instance"

mount() {
    Emitter.on(event1, value => {
      this.method(value);
    });
    Emitter.on(event2, (value) => {
      this.methodtwo(value);
    });
    Emitter.on(event3, value => {
      this.methodThree(value);
    });
}
```

**Environment:**
SonarQube version: 9.3
Vue.js version: 3
Jest version: 29

**Steps to reproduce:**
Make the provided code changes in a Vue.js extension file.
Generate a SonarQube report on the local machine.

**Expected Result:**
The SonarQube report should accurately reflect the minimal changes made, with the correct coverage percentage.

**Actual Result:**
The report is showing 22 uncovered conditions, even though the code changes are limited to three lines.